# How to know the required room temperature for our laptop or desktop

Tags: cpu, temperature, intel-core-i7

Is there any way to get information about "required room temperature for a laptop or desktop.

Because i7 Q720 vs i7 7660U, there is so much improvement in these last 8 year, but we are still working on cool temperatures.

Comment: Check the laptop specifications. There is no broad advice because every laptop is different and is designed differently. One reason that the temperature ranges they are rated for has not changed much is because at the design stage if you realise you have a CPU that runs cooler then generally you will use smaller heatsinks and fans to achieve a similar thermal performance in a smaller space or at a lower cost. It's all swings and roundabouts and depends on a lot of design decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specs for a particular laptop or desktop model should specify the recommended environment temperature during operation and non-operation.